# How to Apply a Texture Classification

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, machine-learning, classification

I am working in medical and nature images processing.
I want to find a popular method to segment texture image.
Could you suggest an approach to do so?

Both the feature extraction and classification.

Comment: Hi! Do you want to segment or to classify? Anyway, there is no silver bullet. I implemented over 15 textural descriptor algorithms (for an older project) and I can't tell you which one is the best. Just to add some more complexity, the algoritm parameters matters a lot!

Comment: @visoft: My task is image segmentation. Now I find that gabor filter is one kind of best method. Which is method that you used

Comment: @John, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You may take one of 2 approaches here:

1. Classic Machine Learning

   - Feature Extraction
     You should use methods such as Wavelet Scattering, SIFT and other [image features](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81040).
   - Classifier
     Probably either Kernel SVM or Boosted Trees.
2. Deep Learning
   If you have many labeled example you may use Deep Learning based approaches. See [Image Texture Analysis Using Deep Neural Networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8300362).
   In this case the net will do the feature extraction for you.
   You should use [Transfer Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) and in case you have many samples yet not many of them are labeled you may use Active Learning / Semi Supervised approaches.

Some nice post about the subject [Texture Analysis with Deep Learning for improved Computer Vision](https://scribe.rip/aa627c8bb133#01a6).